# C# regular expression to find all double quoted text

Tags: c#, regex

Example input

> Throughout this policy the words "you" and "your" refer to the Named
>   Insured shown in the Declarations. The words "we," "us" and "our"
>   refer to the Company providing this insurance. "auto."

I tried something like this `[\s](\\?")(.*?)\1[\s|\n|\t|\b|,|.]`

It is not recognizing `"us"` and `"auto."` [**Regex
 Tester**](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5B%5Cs%5D%28%5C%5C%3F%22%29%28.*%3F%29%5C1%5B%5Cs%7C%5Cn%7C%5Ct%7C%5Cb%7C%2C%7C.%5D&i=Throughout%20this%20policy%20the%20words%20%22you%22%20and%20%22your%22%20refer%20to%20the%20Named%20Insured%20shown%20in%20the%20Declarations.%20The%20words%20%22we%2C%22%20%22us%22%20and%20%22our%22%20refer%20to%20the%20Company%20providing%20this%20insurance.%20%22auto.%22)

There could be other scenarios like

> Throughout this policy the words "you" and "your" refer to the Named
>   Insured shown in the Declarations. The words "we," "us" and "our"
>   refer to "the Company "providing" this insurance". "auto."

Here is another negative test case I need to handle for, I should only consider valid double quotes

> tos" you own. This includes those "autos" you acquire ownership of
>   after the policy begins.

in this example I should be able to remove the full `"the Company "providing" this insurance"`

Comment: How about `(".*?")+`, shown in [your tester](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%22.*%3f%22%29%2b&i=Throughout+this+policy+the+words+%22you%22+and+%22your%22+refer+to+the+Named+Insured+shown+in+the+Declarations.+The+words+%22we%2c%22+%22us%22+and+%22our%22+refer+to+the+Company+providing+this+insurance.+%22auto.%22)

Comment: If you change it to `(\\?")(.*?)\1` then it seems to work. Currently auto doesn't have any of the "after" characters after it and "us" isn't being recognised because the space after "we" is being matched with we and so is not available for matching in "us" it looks like. Is there a reason you need the pre and post characters?

Comment: @AlfieGoodacre your expression works good for positive cases but not for negative case like nested double quotes, please see my updated question with negative case

Comment: Why is `"the Company "providing" this insurance"` a single match while `"we," "us"` are two?

Comment: @HimBromBeere that is a negative scenario client was us to handle, so regex should identify the match as "the Company "providing" this insurance" since "providing" is a nested double quote

Comment: But how do you know that `"provided"` is nested while in the other case it´s not? In particular as you have `"we," "our"` which seems quite similar to what you want as *nested*. I don´t get why it´s not simply `"the company`"  and `" this insureance"`.

Comment: How many nested levels do you expect? Infinite? Or 1 level deep?

Answer (score 0):

If you have nested brackets you need something like a parser.

Otherwise:

```
string input = "Throughout this policy the words \"you\" and \"your\" refer to the Named Insured shown in the Declarations. The words \"we,\" \"us\" and \"our\" refer to the Company providing this insurance. \"auto.\"";
string[] result = Regex.Matches(input, "(\".*?\")+").Cast<Match>().Select(x => x.Value).ToArray();
```

Answer (score 0):

Check this out

```
(["'])(?:(?=(\\?))\2.)*?\1
```

Comment: Although this code might work, you should also explain why this is working and why ops regex is not working.

Answer (score 0):

> If you have nested brackets you need something like a parser.

While this is true for an arbitrary level of nested quotes, it isn't for a limited amount of nesting.
This regular expression handles all given test cases:

```
(?<=\s)"[^"]*(?<=\s)"[^"]*".*?"|(?<=\s)"[^"]*"
```

The subpattern before `|` matches the quotes nested 1 level deep, the subpattern thereafter matches the unnested quotes.